# A good starting point for a solr schema.xml

Tags: solr

I'm trying to get started with solr. My idea was to just have one text field to be indexed (and searched) and to expand from that. This is what I've got so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<schema>
<types>
<fieldType name="long" class="solr.TrieLongField"/>
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField"/>
</types>
<fields>
<field name="_version_" type="long" multiValued="false"/>
<field name="topic" type="text"/>
</fields>
</schema>
```

solr was already driving me crazy with its need for a _version_ field, although the docs say its not mandatory. Anyway, now I'm getting this error:

```
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Unknown FieldType: 'string' used in QueryElevationComponent
```

I just don't get what this is about.

The next thing I tried was to rename the included *managed-schema* to *schema.xml*. That didn't give me any errors, but this file has more than a 1000 lines! Myriads of types, fields, copyFields and so on. Now I guess I could try to strip that file down to my needs, but I would rather go the other way and build one up.

Therefore my question: Is there a minimal, working schema.xml which I can use to build up from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is all the other stuff preconfigured in the **solrconfig.xml**. I have just pushed [a minimal example](https://github.com/arafalov/simplest-solr-config/tree/master/solr-5.5/configset) I used for my training projects. It is for Solr 5.5, not 6.0, but it should give you a really good direction.

This uses static schema approach, not the managed schema one, which is the default in Solr 6. So, that's one of the differences to keep in mind.

Answer (score 2):

The error message is caused by the queryEleveationComponent being enabled, which require a fieldtype named `string` to work. You can either disabled the field, or add a string type (which you're probably going to need anyway):

```
<fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" />
```

StrFields are not tokenized (split into parts) or processed in any way, so they're perfect for filtering and exact searches.

Comment: Thanks, now I've advanced to the next error about not having a uniqueKey Field. I guess I can fix that, but what comes next?
I'm more interested in some sort of guidance about how should I get started. I'm afraid that if I go on just fixing one error after another that I might end up with a pretty messy schema and haven't even learned that much.

Comment: The [reference guide](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Documents%2C+Fields%2C+and+Schema+Design) is the proper place for that. Using one of the examples bundled with Solr as a starting point is usually a good idea as well. But doing it step by step should be a learning experience as well, and you'll probably just rewrite the schema later after adding new fields and getting a feel for how things work.